# Is there a way to change the positions (axis) for a p5 group?

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

As I've been coding, I came across an issue for one of my looped variables. I added the looped variable as shown below, the snake tail, to a group. But, when I tried to set the x and y values to the group so it moves with the snake, it just set to the default of (0,0) and didn't move at all. I do not know if there's a specific function in p5 which changes the group position value, and I've already tried defining the x-pos and y-pos normally. I've already searched the p5 documents and couldn't seem to find anything. Is there any group function to define the positions or any way else
to help define the tail position out of the loop?

```
    if(snake.isTouching(apple)){
      for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
          var tail = createSprite(0,0, snake.width, snake.height);
          
          tail.shapeColor = rgb(Math.round(random(1,255)),Math.round(random(1,255)), 
          Math.round(random(1,255)));
          score = score + 1;
 
          
          apple.x = Math.round(random(245,1700));
          apple.y = Math.round(random(150,700));
      }
   

      tailGroup.add(tail);
 
      }

      if(keyDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
        tailGroup.x = snake.x - 50;
        tailGroup.y = snake.y;
        }
  
        if(keyDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
          tailGroup.x = snake.x + 50;
          tailGroup.y = snake.y;
        }
        
        if(keyDown(UP_ARROW)){
        tailGroup.y = snake.y - 50;
        tailGroup.x = snake.x;
        }
       
        if(keyDown(DOWN_ARROW)){
        tailGroup.y = snake + 50;
        tailGroup.x = snake.x;
        }
```

Comment: `tailGroup.toArray().forEach(tail => {
  tail.x = 30; // some value
  tail.y = 30; // some value
});`

Did you mean something like this?

Comment: @AlveMonke It works, but it deletes the old square when a new one generates